# Expand inner div to fit container

Tags: css

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:bottom;">
        <div class="notiece_board">

        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

I want to increase the height of the notiece_board to fit it with td Then after reached the height of the td the notiece_board must become scrollable. The problem is that, the height of the second td will be increased or decreased dynamically as adding/removing `<div>` in it. The css I used is

```
.notiece_board {
height: 100%;
display:block;
overflow:auto;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a height to the `<td>`.
Then make the `.notiece_board` `overflow:scroll;`and also assign a max-height that matches the td.
Here is fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ap730bj/). You can put the second `<td>` to the same class as notiece_board to avoid dynamic re sizing.

Answer (score 0):

```
table tr td .Notiece_board {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150%; // height have to be more than 100% of the td to make it scroll
    overflow: scroll; // this makes the box scroll
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Not solved my issue. I edited my question. there is another td in the table. this makes the problem. please see

Comment: You have targeted it right, right? Can you post some code?